# Golang dependency management on windows does not work (GOPATH error)

Tags: go, godeps

I try to use to different dependency management tools: [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) and [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep).
And both fail with similar error. How should i set enviroument and where should I put sources?

**dep**

```
PS D:\Work\Golang\src\ChrBack> dep init
root project import: D:\Work\Golang\src\ChrBack is not within any GOPATH/src
```

**godep**

```
PS D:\Work\Golang\src\ChrBack> godep save
godep: [WARNING]: godep should only be used inside a valid go package directory and
godep: [WARNING]: may not function correctly. You are probably outside of your $GOPATH.
godep: [WARNING]:       Current Directory: D:\Work\Golang\src\ChrBack
godep: [WARNING]:       $GOPATH: D:\Work\Golang\src
godep: Unable to find SrcRoot for package .
```

**Go env**

```
$ D:\Work\Golang\Go\bin\go.exe version
go version go1.9.1 windows/amd64

$ D:\Work\Golang\Go\bin\go.exe env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=D:\Work\Golang\src\bin
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\Work\Golang\src
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=D:\Work\Golang\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=D:\Work\Golang\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
```

Comment: Your `GOPATH` should not include the `src` directory as part of the path, `src` should be inside the directory `GOPATH` describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set

```
GOPATH=D:\Work\Golang
```

Then create folders like  `src\github.com\user\repo` and keep you in them.